# Disable broken portion of screen

Tags: windows-10

I have cracked part of my screen and i would like to "cut" that part off (effectively turning my 1920x1080 into a 1560x1080 screen)

I tried to utlize several tools like

- "MS Powertoys for Win 10"
- "DisplayFusion"

but either i am too stupid to configure them correctly or they both offer something i confused with what i search for.

I don't know how this question doesn't satisfy standards though because i wrote down everything i know and want to know...